# When limit of subsequences in strong and weak topology are same?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $(X, \|\cdot \|)$ be a infinite dimesionsal Banach space with the topology generated by norm $\|\cdot \|,$ that is,  we say strong topology. (For instance, take $X=L^2$)

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a bounded sequence in $X$ with  resopect  to the strong topology.
 Next we give a [weak topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology) on $X,$ and assume that $\{x_{n}\}$ converge weakly to some $x\in X.$

> My Question: Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ have a convergent subsequence (in the strong topology), say $\{y_{n}\}$, more spacefically, $\|y_n-y\|_{X}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty.$  Can we say $x=y$? If yes, how to justify?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing to check is that strong convergence implies weak convergence.  Then, if the su sequence is strongly convergent it will also be weakly convergent  (and to the same limit).